# DefaultAzureCredential throwing unknown error

Tags: azure

I am trying to set up a Azure webapp service (uses docker) to access my keyvault using a user manged identity.  I have setup up a user managed identity, assigned it to my webapp and gave it the access policies that it will need in the keyvault I am testing it on (see abbreviated settings below).

In the webapp application settings, I have have included a setting for AZURE_CLIENT_ID that I have set to the the client id of my user managed identity and it is being injected into the environmental variables.

My app is node and I am using DefaultAzureCredential from the @azure/identity npm package:

`const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();`

I also tried:

`const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential({managedIdentityClientId: '27455443-73e6-4386-aef2-05c8be5586af'});`

From everything that I can see it should be working, but I always get the following error back:

```
AuthenticationError: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed.(status code 400).
More details:
unknown_error(status code 400).
More details:
An unknown error occurred and no additional details are available.
    at ManagedIdentityCredential.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@azure/identity/dist/index.js:1077:23)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/usr/src/app/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:112:69)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

App service identity setting (abbreviated):

```
            "identity": {
                "type": "UserAssigned",
                "userAssignedIdentities": {
                    "/subscriptions/f3f6b1b3-6e32-4fe1-ac75-41f1b2c8731f/resourcegroups/keyVaultAccess/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/accesstokeyvault": {
                        "principalId": "46eeaff7-d686-4a07-8471-90a6f892a1b4",
                        "clientId": "27455443-73e6-4386-aef2-05c8be5586af"
                    }
                }
            },
```

Keyvault access policy (abbreviated):

```
                    {
                        "tenantId": "26332e31-5b20-48a7-b449-cdae84c6c7df",
                        "objectId": "46eeaff7-d686-4a07-8471-90a6f892a1b4",
                        "permissions": {
                            "keys": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create",
                                "Import",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore"
                            ],
                            "secrets": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Set",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore"
                            ],
                            "certificates": [
                                "Get",
                                "List",
                                "Update",
                                "Create",
                                "Import",
                                "Delete",
                                "Recover",
                                "Backup",
                                "Restore",
                                "ManageContacts",
                                "ManageIssuers",
                                "GetIssuers",
                                "ListIssuers",
                                "SetIssuers",
                                "DeleteIssuers"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
```

User managed identity:

```
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "userAssignedIdentities_accesstokeyvault_name": {
            "defaultValue": "accesstokeyvault",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities",
            "apiVersion": "2018-11-30",
            "name": "[parameters('userAssignedIdentities_accesstokeyvault_name')]",
            "location": "westus"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have figured it out. Instead of using managedIdentityClientId in the function, I set the environmental variable AZURE_CLIENT_ID to the client ID of my user managed identity and that seemed to work.

I had not worked on this in a while, so cannot be sure that was what fixed it but if you run into this issue it is probably something that you will want to try.